# Div toggler - toggle curent div event-description

Tags: jquery, toggle

First, I need to say I'm a beginner in jQuery and I need this for for my HTML/JS class. So here is what I need to do

```
    <div class="event">
    <div class="event-bar">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td class="space" colspan="7">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="event-date"><p>22 IV</p></td>
                <td class="event-place">19.30<br/>Kościół Księży Misjonarzy</td>
                <td class="event-doc">carte blanche</td>
                <td class="event-title">johann sebastian bach<br/>Pasja wg św. Mateusza</td>
                <td class="event-performers">Anna Schoek<br/>Stefan Telefan<br/>Lorem Ipsum</td>
                <td class="event-leader">dyrygent</td>
                <td class="event-toggler"><div class="toggler"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="space" colspan="7">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="event-description">
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The thing I need to achieve is div. toggler which when pressed should toggle div. event-description, there are X div.event. Every time you click div. toggler should only toggle current div event-description and hide other if other is open (one toggle at a time).

I cannot really do a fight with `.parent()` to get outside table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new css class - hidden:
then in css:

```
.hidden {display:none;}
```

jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.toggler').click(function () {
            $('.event-description').addClass('hidden');
            $(this).parents('.event:first').find('.event-description').removeClass('hidden');
        });
    });
```

should do it.

Comment: oops sorry - missed the find!

Comment: works almost great, what i did was: jquery:

`$('.toggler').click(function(){
         $(this).parents('.event:first').find('.event-description').toggle(); 
       });`
       
but it doesnt hide other open .event-description, only one should be visible at a time

Comment: Finally i've managed to achieve what i've wanted. Thanks BonyT for leading me to it!

       `$('.toggler').click(function(){
         $('#events-list').find('.event-description').hide();
         $(this).parents('.event:first').find('.event-description').fadeToggle(); 
       });`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need jquery Accordion http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
$(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
div.panel,p.flip
{
margin:0px;
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
background:#70DBFF;
border:solid 1px #33CCFF;
}
div.panel
{
height:400px;
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
Hi skcjlvbcuvb cxkjvcxjkvhcxj vxcjvhxjchvjxck vxcjvjkxchv xcvkjxcvjkxcjv

cxkvbxcjkv xckjvbjxck vjcxkbv

<div class="panel">
<p>hi...................................</p>
<p>describe data to be toggle her. this can be used any side / place of a web page</p>
</div>
<input type="button" class="flip" value="Show/Hide Panel" />

</body>
</html>
```